# Ninja-IDE TERM environment variable?

Tags: python, environment-variables

I am attempting to use the `os` module in Python to clear the screen. As I'm using Fedora, the standard console command to clear the display is `clear`. When I type the following into a .py file:

```
from os import system

system("clear")
print("Hello world")
```

and run the file by opening a standard Terminal window and calling the file directly using the `python` shell command, it all works fine. However, if I type the same code into Ninja-IDE and execute it in the embedded console there, what comes out is the message "TERM environment variable not set" wherever I wanted to clear the screen.

Now, I'm aware that I can set the TERM environment variable if it is non-existant using something like this:

```
import os
try:
    print(os.environ['TERM'])
except KeyError:
    os.environ['TERM'] = foo
```

but, I'm unsure exactly what to set it to so that it works in Ninja-IDE. I've tried some of the obvious - `xterm`, `xterm-256color`, `konsole` - but they do not work for Ninja-IDE. Which leads to my question: what is the appropriate value of the TERM environment variable corresponding to the embedded console in Ninja-IDE? Or, alternatively, is it possible to tell Ninja-IDE to invoke an external terminal (such as xterm) when executing code, rather than using its own inbuilt console?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. It is caused by **os.system**. Simply add **import system** to your code and it is done, like this:

```
import os
import system
import shutil
import datetime

os.system('clear')
```